# Como fazer expressão regular para aceitar palavras e depois 2 números com jQuery, sem caracteres especiais?

Tags: jquery, regex

Olá, pessoal. Seguinte, estou fazendo uma expressão regular para aceitar o seguinte: Palavra 02.
Palavra e números, não apenas números.
Estou usando este código:

```
$(".inputNomeTurma").keyup(function() {
    var valor = $(this).val().replace(/(([a-zA-Z]*\d{3,})|[!"#$%&'()*+ºª,-./:;<=>?@[\]_{|}])/,'');
    $(this).val(valor);
});
```

Fica ok, se eu clicar em um caractere * por exemplo, ele faz o replace. Mas se eu apertar e segurar o *, o campo aceita o caractere especial.

Comment: Sendo bem simples add o caractere `g` no final da sua regex `/REGEX/g`, seja se funciona.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem mas veja se é isso https://regex101.com/r/sU8fF3/3

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi isso deve resolver

> /[^\w]/g

```
[^\w] corresponde a um caractere único não está presente na lista abaixo
   \w corresponde a qualquer caractere de palavra [a-zA-Z0-9_]
modificador g: global
```

ou talvez isso se encaixe melhor no seu problema:

```
$(".inputNomeTurma").keyup(function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var reg   = /([a-zA-Z])+([0-9]{2})/g;
    var encontrados = reg.exec(valor);
    console.log(encontrados);
    $(this).val(encontrados[0]);
});
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui.